# Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?

Tags: html, input, datepicker

I am really stoked about the HTML5 date picker.

The caveat is that I don't see or foresee much in the way of applying colors to the picker itself which is going to make the use of the datepicker kind of a deal-breaker on most sites. The `<select>` suffers from widespread JavaScript-replacement hacks for the simple reason that people can't make it pretty.

So are there any known styling options for the HTML input of `type='date'`?

Comment: Haven't tried it out due to the lack of support it had but I am guessing styling is minimal going by the `<select>` input.

Comment: I have to say that things advance very slowly in the W3C world. Browsers devs/companies will prefer to move to where there is interest. They (browsers) will be reluctant to implement things that are not well specified in W3C (and cooking those docs take time). More the people faster the things can be achieved. So, yes, if you have interest, join their mailing list and start get involved.

Comment: In order to check more pseudo elements in future - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852922/inspect-webkit-input-placeholder-with-developer-tools/26853319#26853319

Answer (score 306, accepted):

The following pseudo-elements are made available by WebKit for customizing a [`date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), [`datetime-local`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local), [`month`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month), [`week`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/week), or [`time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) input’s textbox:

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text

::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-week-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-second-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-millisecond-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field

::-webkit-inner-spin-button
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator
```

I found these attribute names in [Chromium’s default “user agent” stylesheet](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/e7ad60a5304c2196e0123dcd7cee0804f7f317b1/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css#L1294-L1322).

Note that some subset of the `edit-...-field` pseudo elements are included depending on the type of input, the `step` attribute on the input, and the user’s locale.

So if you thought the date input could use more spacing and a ridiculous color scheme you could add the following:

```css
::-webkit-datetime-edit { padding: 1em; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper { background: silver; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text { color: red; padding: 0 0.3em; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field { color: blue; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field { color: green; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field { color: purple; }
::-webkit-inner-spin-button { display: none; }
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { background: orange; }
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: using input[type="date"] worked for my purposes and maybe that will work for someone else too.

Comment: Note that you can style the clear button too with the pseudo-class `::-webkit-clear-button`

Comment: A source for these pseudo-classes would make this an even better answer...

Comment: You need to write `input::...` for each entry

Comment: @HereticMonkey you can find a pretty good list in Chrome’s default stylesheet: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/378282f368bf00e9a63c4f06c62ed0f6a0d639c1/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css#L1298-L1322

Comment: @LukeTaylor That link would look better in the answer itself, rather than as an easily lost comment...

Answer (score 32):

Currently, there is no cross browser, script-free way of styling a native date picker.

As for what's going on inside WHATWG/W3C...
If this functionality does emerge, it will likely be under the [CSS-UI](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/) standard or some [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/)-related standard. The [CSS4-UI wiki page](http://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css4-ui) lists a few appearance-related things that were dropped from CSS3-UI, but to be honest, there doesn't seem to be a great deal of interest in the CSS-UI module.

I think your best bet for cross browser development right now, is to implement pretty controls with JavaScript based interface, and then disable the HTML5 native UI and replace it. I think in the future, maybe there will be better native control styling, but perhaps more likely will be the ability to swap out a native control for your own Shadow DOM "widget".

It is annoying that this isn't available, and petitioning for standard support is always worthwhile. Though it does seem like jQuery UI's lead [has tried and was unsuccessful](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8567).

While this is all very discouraging, it's also worth considering the advantages of the HTML5 date picker, and also why custom styles are difficult and perhaps should be avoided. On some platforms, the datepicker [looks extremely different](http://www.deque.com/wbcntnt928/wp-content/dquploads/iphone-input-type-date.png) and I personally can't think of any generic way of styling the native datepicker.

Answer (score 21):

FYI, I needed to update the color of the calendar icon which didn't seem possible with properties like `color`, `fill`, etc.

I did eventually figure out that some `filter` properties will adjust the icon so while i did not end up figuring out how to make it any color, luckily all I needed was to make it so the icon was visible on a dark background so I was able to do the following:

```css
body { background: black; }

input[type="date"] { 
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<body>
 <input type="date" />
</body>
```

Hopefully this helps some people as for the most part chrome even directly says this is impossible.

Comment: These days I believe `color-scheme: dark` is the recommended way to accomplish the same behavior (less “hacky” than using filters) https://stackoverflow.com/a/77794970/4414003

Comment: Yes, this was quite awhile ago now :-). -- still wish there were more options though!

Answer (score 15):

found this on [Zurb Foundation's GitHub](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1877#issuecomment-15088274)

> In case you want to do some more custom styling. Here's all the
> default CSS for webkit rendering of the date components.
>
> ```
> input[type="date"] {
>      -webkit-align-items: center;
>      display: -webkit-inline-flex;
>      font-family: monospace;
>      overflow: hidden;
>      padding: 0;
>      -webkit-padding-start: 1px;
> }
>
> input::-webkit-datetime-edit {
>     -webkit-flex: 1;
>     -webkit-user-modify: read-only !important;
>     display: inline-block;
>     min-width: 0;
>     overflow: hidden;
> }
>
> input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
>     -webkit-user-modify: read-only !important;
>     display: inline-block;
>     padding: 1px 0;
>     white-space: pre;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 9):

I used a combination of the above solutions and some trial and error to come to this solution.

I am using styled-components to render a transparent date picker input as shown in the image below:

[image: image of date picker input]

```
const StyledInput = styled.input`
  appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 8px;
  ::-webkit-datetime-edit-text { padding: 0 2rem; }
  ::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field { text-transform: uppercase; }
  ::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field { text-transform: uppercase; }
  ::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field { text-transform: uppercase; }
  ::-webkit-inner-spin-button { display: none; }
  ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { background: transparent;}
`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following CSS to style the input element.

```css
input[type="date"] {
  background-color: red;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button {
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  height: 28px;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" value="From" name="from" placeholder="From" required="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `color-scheme: dark` on a `date` or `datetime-local` input will also make the calendar icon light-colored in Chrome, without having to use CSS filters as a workaround.

```css
body { background: black; }

input[type="date"] { 
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: none;

  color-scheme: dark;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <input type="date" />
</body>
```