# Angular event detection for datepicker close

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datepicker

I have just started using angular and in general love it. I have a UI requirement to show a date as text, then when you click on the text, it shows a date picker instead. Then when you select a date it goes back to text. Sounds simple.

I have tried a few variations on the below code the object being edited holds a value called editdate, clicking on the text box changes this to true and hides the text and shows the editor. This works fine, the problem is hiding the date picker. I tried adding ng-blur to the datepicker to cause the box to hide when it looses focus, but this was very intermittent as to if it worked. I then tried ng-Mouseleave but the box closed when I moved the mouse pointer into the date picker from the text box.

```
<td colspan="7">
    Required Date : <span ng-click="item.editdate=true; item.delayeditclose = true;" ng-show="!item.editdate">{{item.dueDate.toDateString()}}</span>  
    <input type="date" ng-blur="item.editdate=false" ng-click="item.switcheditdate(item.delayeditclose)"  ng-show="item.editdate" class="datepick" ng-model="item.dueDate" ng-focus="selectPart(item.partNumber)" />
</td>
```

The javascript is initialized as:

```
                for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                    item = data.items[i];
                    item.showExpanded = false;
                    item.editdate = false;
                    item.delayeditclose = true;
                    item.switcheditdate = function (delayclose) {
                        if (!delayclose) {
                            this.editdate = !this.editdate;
                            this.delayeditclose = true;
                        }
                        this.delayeditclose = false;

                    };
                    items.push(item);
           }
```

I have now moved onto the above which almost does the job. The new issue being html5 date pickers seem to have a x to close them down. This hides the whole box and not just the picker part. If this happens I want to show the text of the date rather than what I get now which is nothing. Does anyone know of how I can capture this close event and revert back to the text or suggest a better approach to the problem?

I have lots of items each one is in its own row in a table

I am using angular 1.3 beta 8

thanks for looking
Andy

Comment: Please give more detail of your code or an example.

Comment: What datepicker are you using? Your own custom one or from an existing library? Also, this would probably be better if you made a custom directive for it.

Comment: Its the browsers html5 one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting nothing is because when you click `x` what happens is that the date value gets cleared so then your date view is an empty string.  What you can do is set a condition to display a string such as "Click to Edit" when the date is empty.

Taking just what you have above, one way of doing it is by adding an element and a flag in your date "view".  So change this:

```
Required Date : <span ng-click="item.editdate=true; item.delayeditclose = true;" ng-show="!item.editdate">{{item.dueDate.toDateString()}}</span>
```

To:

```
Required Date : 
<span ng-click="item.editdate=true; item.delayeditclose = true;" ng-show="!item.editdate">
    <span>{{item.dueDate.toDateString()}}</span>
    <span ng-show="!item.dueDate">Click to Edit</span>
</span>
```

**The directive way**

Now in my opinion I think it's much better to use a directive for this.  It would simplify your logic and is much easier to re-use.  I created a [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EEMqWVp0KjmO47QXNrlE?p=preview) which shows my implementation using a directive.

**Answer to question in title**

To answer the question posed by your title, when using the html5 date picker, you can't detect when it is closed (or even when it is opened).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18327043/238427) and the linked [Quick FAQs on input[type=date]](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome)