# How to trigger mouse click event on react component to open date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using reactjs and I have one button and one input date dom on my react component. I want to open the date picker when click on the button. The input date dom defined as below

```
<input className='showSurgeryDate' type="date"
                     onChange={this.setSurgeryDate.bind(this)} ref={(c) => this.datePicker = c }/>
```

below is the onclick function defined on the button:

```
let event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
let dom = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.datePicker)
event.initEvent('click', true, false)
dom.dispatchEvent(event)
```

I use document.createEvent to create a click event. Then I call dispatchEvent on the dom but the date picker didn't popup. How can I let the date picker popup when user clicking on the button?

Comment: You should not need to simulate a mouse click event. What are you using as the date picker? Is it a React component or is something like jQuery UI datepicker (3rd party, non-React)?

Comment: The date picker is just the html <input type='date'> tag. I want to click the button to open the date picker on that tag.

Comment: You can't manually open the html5 date picker. You'll need to use a library that supports that action such as jQueryUI datepicker or bootstrap date picker.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631562/how-do-i-open-the-window-in-a-date-type-input-through-code/33986228#33986228

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I have to use third party library for date picker.