# how to remove elements of datepicker in HTML5 input=date that appears on the far right on hovering

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

**Problem :**

- How can I remove the caret and incrementor/decrementor that appears when I hover over the matInput `type=date`.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo with no hovered increment/decrement icons](https://angular-incons-hide-input-type-date.stackblitz.io)

**Application Code :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-incons-hide-input-type-date?file=src/app/app.component.css

**Approach :**

- I looked for the things that are applied on `:hover` of matinput but no luck, 
  So i tricked by making a mask of white color which will cover that icons using `:before`.

  > This will hide those icons and their actions will not be available like opening of calendar dialog on clicking from icon, as icon is hidden.

**Code :**

Give class to input tag 
`<input class="myInput" matInput type="date" placeholder="no icons on hover" value="">`, 
then add following css

```
.myInput::before {
    content: 'we';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: actually it is not related to material per se..it appears by default for all html input type=date..so is there a method to make it disappear?

Comment: and also i want the datepicker to open when i click on the input field..is there a method for it?

Comment: @chaucer yes, its for those where you will give this particular class `myInput`, and according to material there is different date picker for this, they don't use type='date' with matInput. See Datepicker docs : https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: See this if its helpful, we can't have control over html5 input with type date, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326982/open-html5-date-picker-on-icon-click/#answer-18327043, i will suggest to use datepicker component from angular.

Comment: I was looking at my problem wrongly..I am just having

Comment: See this also, it may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker#16106788/#answer-16106788

Comment: I want the datepicker to open on clicking the input field ..is that possible?

Comment: @chaucer i tried but no luck, i guess you can style your input with this only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker#16106788/#answer-16106788, as we have to deal with those icons from html5. As these are not present in html, if present, we can bind their click or call but all we have is input field and focusing clicking on that is not opening the dialog.