# How to open Datepicker dialog box on click of input box not icon or arrow

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I want to open datepicker dialog box on click of input box as well as icon.

 my code: `<input type="date" name="bday" id="bday" >` 
 Is there any way to fix this using **JavaScript ONLY**.

Comment: have a look at : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Insee the jquery tag in the question so have you tried `$(#bday).on('click', function() { $(this).datepicker() }` or just `$('#bday').datepicker()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `input type="date"` is not supported in Safari or Internet Explorer 11 and earlier versions, so I wouldn't recommend using that - see this link https://caniuse.com/#search=date

Here is a simple example using the [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io) that is cross-browser compatible

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ybtzqoL7/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[id="js-date"]').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

<h3>Bootstrap datepicker demo</h3>

<div class="input-group date">
  <label for="js-date">Date:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="js-date">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks @Marc , but is there any to do it without changing _type='date'_ to _type='text'_

Comment: I don't see any reason to use `input type="date"`, due to the poor support of several browsers. Why do you want to use date?

Comment: type='date' is default type for date field in sitecore (content management application) and it seems they cannot use text field in that place .

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**.

Also, this is a duplicated question, see: [Open HTML5 date picker on icon click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326982/open-html5-date-picker-on-icon-click)

Comment: correct , using JS it is difficult  it seems. And in duplicate qus noone answered correctly