# Select new input to fire flatpickr

Tags: javascript

I have a date picker that when I choose a new date I wish to fire another date picker on another input

Input one:

```
<input name="pDate" type="text" class="form-control date-with-time-inputs" onchange="changeDate()" id="p_date" placeholder="" value="{{$times['now']}}">
```

Then I have onchange event

```
<script>
     function changeDate() {
     const input = document.getElementById('d_date');
     input.select();
     console.log('clicked');
   }
</script>
```

And then the second input as so

```
<input name="dDate" type="date" class="form-control date-with-time-inputs" id="d_date" placeholder="" value="{{$times['tomorrow']}}">
```

The console log fires and the function is working but the 2nd input is not firing up.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open/click() it from JS(only focus() but that would not help you):

> The HTML5 `<input>` with `type='date'` will only work with a [few browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime).
>   Also, as a programmer you have no control over its appearance or any
>   other aspect (such as showing and hiding it) [(Quick FAQs on input type date)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome)
>
> Thus, if you must do this, the HTML5 `<input type='date'>` tag is not an
>   option. You'll have to use something build in JavaScript such as
>   [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or [Bootstrap](https://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) date picker.

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18327043/12753766