# Customizing the look of the default datepicker

Tags: css, html, input

I recently found out about an HTML input type called `date`, and it has a basic visual interface for selecting a date (it's really cool). 
However, I don't really like the basic look, and I was wondering - is it possible to customize it with CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Comment: @RussCam I actually meant the little popup, not the little input field.