# HTML5 input date calendar styling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dom

I just discovered this HTML5 feature, and I managed to style *some* input properties.

So in Chrome this input opens an awesome calendar box and I want to style it. I didn't find anything via Google search. Is there some documentation for chrome date input type of this calendar, and is there a way of styling it?

I'm not interested on cross-browser support, and I don't want to use jQueryUI, or anything like that.

I'm using Angular2 and typescript and just plugging jQuery into that makes my stomach sick.

I'm only going to be using this on Chrome (no other browser support necessary).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Answer (score 2):

According to

[Styling the calendar for html5 native datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531587/styling-the-calendar-for-html5-native-datepicker?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and

[Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker/16106788#16106788)

it doesn't seem like it's possible. Probably for good reason too - who knows what kind of chaos would ensue if browser specific widget styling of this magnitude was allowed. I think Chrome just provides this as a simple usability improvement for users.

Answer (score -2):

There is a PrimeFaces calendar that is very useful.

[Prime Calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)