# Styling the HTML5 date

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a hard time to style the HTML5 date picker, i just want to change the color of the current/selected day i need to remove the blue color! does any one know how to do so. here is a codepen https://codepen.io/MuTLY/pen/VvJaMx

In this example you can style the color of the text of the input, but i have no idea how to target the style (background-color) of the current/selected day

```
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field {
    color: red;
  }
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field {
    color: white;
  }
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field {
    color: blue;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling the calendar for html5 native datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531587/styling-the-calendar-for-html5-native-datepicker)

Comment: You can only influence the style of the input box area ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)), but not the style of the date picker popup content ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164546/html5-input-date-calendar-styling/40166561#40166561) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531587/styling-the-calendar-for-html5-native-datepicker?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with adding the `:focus` selector. E.g.:

```
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field {
    color: red;
  }
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field {
    color: white;
  }
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:focus {
    color: purple;
  }
  &::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field {
    color: blue;
  }
```

Here the day is white unless it is selected, then is turns purple.

Comment: the background of the current day stays blue! nothing has changed

Comment: Are you sure? Here is a fork where I applied my changes: https://codepen.io/achimcc/pen/abBzjzX If I go there and click on the day field, it turns purple. Or is this not what you wanted?

Comment: I think I got now, what you are looking for @Elchy! You want to style something within the Datepicker window which opens, once you click on the Calendar icon, correct? I'm convinced, that this is not possible, since this is a native browser functionality. Try it on different Browsers, e.g. Safari, Chrome, IE, it will always look completely different! If you want to have  a customised styling for this, you will have to install some external Datepicker library.