# CSS for styling HTML5 date input calendar in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, date, input

Is there a way to style the calendar that pops up if you click the down arrow on a html5 date input?

```
<form>
    <label for="f-duedate">Due date</label>
        <input id="f-duedate" type="date" name="duedate"
               data-date-format="dd.mm.YYYY">
</form>
```

[image: a html5 calendar]

http://jsfiddle.net/no8a17eo/1/

I know there are pseudo selectors for styling the input field itself:

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
}
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
}
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field, 
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field, 
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field {
}
::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display: none;
}
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator:hover {
   background:none;
}
```

*At the bare minimum I only need it to work on the latest version of Google Chrome*

Comment: Duplicated I think,  checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16106788/2104879

Comment: No, I'm not asking about the input field, I need a way to style the calendar. Also, I do not require a Cross Browser solution.

Comment: @meatFeed I know your pain, dumb-dumbs who think the color red is a duplicate of the color blue; the reputation system on Stack is explicitely *not* correlated to *competence*!

Answer (score 4):

According to Google's FAQ, there is no way to modify the style at this time: 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome

> **How do I change the appearance of the date picker?**
>
> You cannot
>   currently style the appearance of the date picker. In WebKit, we have
>   previously provided ways to style form controls with the
>   -webkit-appearance CSS property or the ::-webkit-foo pseudo class selector. 
>   *However the calendar popup does not provide such ways in WebKit because it is separate from the document, like a popup menu for , and there is not currently a standard for how to control styling on its sub-elements.*

You are left with keeping with Chrome's rendering, or using a custom library over an `input type="text"` field to prevent conflicts

Comment: Side note: the article was written in 2012, which is why it references WebKit. Chrome's current engine (Blink) was released in 2013.