# How can I customize input date with css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input, sass

I am trying customize my input date pick like this design here:

[image]

here is my following code and default design:

```
  <input
    type="date"
    name="date"
    defaultValue={currentDate || dateInput}
    onChange={(e) => setDateInput(e.target.value)}
    required
  />
```

[image]

How can I edit it with css or scss?

Comment: Hi There. You would have to add more details. Are you using any package for the date picker ? What is your approach so far ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS for styling HTML5 date input calendar in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738112/css-for-styling-html5-date-input-calendar-in-chrome)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Answer (score -5):

You need to add class:

```
<input
    className="datePicker"
    type="date"
    name="date"
    defaultValue={currentDate || dateInput}
    onChange={(e) => setDateInput(e.target.value)}
    required
  />
```

And in css:

```
.datePicker {
  background-color: red;

}
```

Comment: It change the input background not the datepicker

Comment: @nathan I don't think there's any cross-browser way of styling it since every browser implements their own calendar differently. If you want to do it you have to create your own calendar with JS.