# how to style html5 date input, first element focus/active

Tags: css, html, date, input, css-selectors

I have a date input that I've styled but I can't remove a blue highlight.

Here is a pen:

http://codepen.io/pjrundle/pen/PqjKBZ

```
<input id="selectedDate" type="date" class="date-filter pseudo-input live-update" placeholder="Event Date">

::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        display: none;
    }
    ::-webkit-clear-button {
        display: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
        opacity: 0;
        height: 14px;
        width: 80px;
        border: 1px solid green;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        left: 9px;
        top: 8px;
    }
```

so when you click on the input, the first element should not go blue. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What part of this code makes it so that when you click anywhere on this field, the popup appears? In my code I am forced to click the picker button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first element goes blue to indicate that it is the active element (in case you want to update the date using the keyboard), you can style it by specifying that it should not have a background using the pseudo-elements:

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field
```

**Notice**: you should style not only the month, but all three elements (day/month/year) as you don't know which date format the user's computer will have. The code would be like this:

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field { background: none; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field { background: none; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field { background: none; }
```

---

And your example would look like this:

```css
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field { background: none; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field { background: none; }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field { background: none; }

::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}
::-webkit-clear-button {
  display: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 14px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 9px;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<input id="selectedDate" type="date" class="date-filter pseudo-input live-update" placeholder="Event Date">
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker) for a list of all the pseudo-elements that you can use.

Comment: What part of this code makes it so that when you click anywhere on this field, the popup appears? In my code I am forced to click the picker button.