# How to underline date/time <input> value using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to underline an `<input type="date">` field using `style="text-decoration: underline;"` but it doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to underline the set date value? I would also like to apply this for time.

**NOTE** I am able to apply `font-weight` and `color` properties to these inputs but not `text-decoration`

**EDIT**

It seems the above is not a sufficient explanation of what I am trying to achieve.

Basically:

`<input type="date">` will yield `15-02-17`

I am trying something like:

`<input type="date" style="text-decoration: underline;">` to yield an underlined `15-02-17`

But this does not work. Is there another way?

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Preferably the solution should be generalized to all browsers.

Comment: Please share what you have tried till now

Comment: It seems to work, tested on chrome, ff, and safari. https://jsfiddle.net/sb45dcjd/

Comment: works also with FF and Opera ... Can you clarify your question with an example that demonstrate your issue ?

Comment: OP asked to style DATE -- doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/h16bxftv/

Comment: @SaurabhSharma I just said that I tried using `style="text-decoration: underline;"` in the `<input type="date">` tag. 

@JonasGiuro Yes I've already tested for `type="text"`, I would like to apply the same thing to `type="date"`

Comment: `input[type="date"] {/*style here */}`  ? ... clarify your question please

Comment: @GCyrillus https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/onycfqo2/ -- also doesn't work

Comment: Ah ok - then you need something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/h16bxftv/1/) - from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in the CSS.

```
input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

The date  tag consists of different div and span tags, which are enveloped by `input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper` in Chrome

**EDIT :** Example date input tag in Chrome

[image: DOM: Example date input tag in Chrome]

Comment: @ovokuro but works fine for opera and IE11 (styling form elements is always failing here or there, ...  you need to let it go at one point. )

Comment: @ovokuro no problem (Edge doesn't use the WebKit engine, which is why the solution doesn't work for it). Well, now it's just needed to find out how the wrapper is called in Edge.

Comment: Preferably but not strictly across all browsers. The solution will mainly be used in a Cordova Webview container and it works on both Android and iOS platforms. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can style `<input type="date">` with text-decoration.

Not the nicest solution, but you could manually add an underline..

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 4px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 54%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="date">
</div>
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/LxaLPR)

Note that you can't add pseudoelement to input, so you'll have to position it relative to something else.

Comment: ?? `input[type="date"] {
  color: red;
  text-decoration:underline
}`-  `<input type="date" value="01/01/01">`works fine ...

Comment: @GCyrillus That's the first thing I tried. I'm viewing on Chrome and the underline isn't there. https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/onycfqo2/1/

Comment: Nice solution to avoid just targeting webkit browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm affraid the visualization of html5 inputs is browser-specific (kinda like fieldsets), thats why `text-decoration: underline;` won't work. You will likely run into issues too when trying to style the calendar it is showing.

I think your best bet is to use a plugin. There are plenty ot there, ie: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker

Also, you can edit your question and ask for the specific browser you want to do this, I'm sure we can find out the style needed.