# Is there any way to select for the native placeholder of an input[type=date] in browsers other than Chrome?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've seen this question asked once before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486722/css-styling-for-inputtype-date-for-browsers-other-than-chrome), unfortunately the poster accepted an answer that I don't think answers the question at all. Just like that poster, I am aware of how to style the placeholder for an empty date and time input in Chrome, but not in any other browsers. I thought I would be able to find a `-moz` pseudo but so far I have not been able to.

I could change the `color` styling of the input, but I would need to only style it when the input was empty, which I could do programmatically, but I am hoping there are better methods.

Comment: I guess the issue with `input[type="date"]` elements is that they don't accept the placeholder attribute - which in turn means what you see is basically the initial value, not a stylable placeholder.

Comment: Right, it's just an element tagged on through a shadow DOM. In Chrome, it can be styled, but I haven't found any consistent way of doing so in all browsers, or even a method of doing so in all browsers that varies.

Comment: Further it's even complicated to make a good user experience programmatically, as date type inputs do not report a value until a full date is entered, so you wouldn't be able to detect partial entries to change the style, as far as I can tell.