# Why does Chrome hide part of the dropdowns input?

Tags: html, css

I've been developing angular apps for a while now, but recently I found an issue in displaying a basic input with type=date in chrome, and I wonder if there is a css trick that I don't know about to let it work.

[image: What happens when I open the dropdown]

As you can see, the Monday column is entirely missing.
The code is as simple as it should be, it's basic HTML:

```html
<input type="date">
```

And the funny fact is that as soon as I resize the window (for example opening and closing the developers console) it starts working fine.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

EDIT: 
I don't think the issue is with my code at all.

[image: You can look at this snapshot taken from another question here on stackoverflow, and here too the date picker doesn't show correctly]

([Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker))

Comment: I think it is being affected by its sibling or parent elements by position or z-index. Am not sure though! Can you create a fiddle and add it so that I can help.

Comment: I could, but the issue isn't really with my code! If I go to this other question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker) and run the snippet of the accepted answer, even there I can't see the monday column... I think this is an issue in chrome itself. @YogarajSaravanan

Comment: okay, Check whether you have updated version of the chrome then

Comment: The issue is still probably with your code. I'm unable to reproduce it in Chrome by simply putting an `<input type="date">`. I see all the content.

Comment: Thanks @YogarajSaravanan but before opening this question I disabled all the addons and checked if I'm on the latest version of Chrome, and I am.

Comment: @D.Troise Unable to reproduce.  Did you try incognito mode?  Tested on `Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Comment: Looks just fine by me. Chrome 75 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/18bLa.png

Comment: It seems that the issue is related to my second monitor. When I open my app or anything else on the actual screen of my laptop, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is more related to my second monitor than to chrome itself.
If I open my app or any dropdown on the web from my laptop monitor it shows correctly.

Thank you everybody for the help.

Comment: Interesting, I guess it could be tied to different pixel density and/or OS zoom level screens. Could that be a Chrome bug in the end, not resizing that kind of "Chrome native" helper ?