# Native Html Datepicker Styling

Tags: html, css, input, user-input

sommeone knows how i can change the color of the text, after an User select a date?
If possible achiev it only with css.

I have this colors:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-text { color: #dbdbdb }
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field { color: #dbdbdb; }
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field { color: #dbdbdb; }
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field { color: #dbdbdb; }
```

So, after the User choice a date, I wanna change this input text/placeholder color.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could achieve that by making the input field required and then using the pseudo-element for the input field.

```css
.form-control:valid {
  color: green;
}
.form-control:invalid {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
   <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Your input" required>
```

If you don t want to make the field required, you can use the pseudo-element "placeholder-shown".

```
input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  color: green;
}

input:placeholder-shown {
  color: black;
}
```

Might reach more devices than only using WebKit technology

Comment: Your solution works very well.
I did a test with a new html.

But isnt working with Bulma Framework, idk why.