# How do I change the position of the datepicker/calendar icon in my bootstrap form?

Tags: html, css, input, datepicker, react-bootstrap

I using react-bootstrap <Form.Control type="date"> and the calendar icon or date picker is automatically set to the right side/end of the form field. I would like to move the calendar icon/date picker to the left/beginning of the form field or so it immediately follows the date. I tried to find the proper node_module to change the CSS code for the calendar icon's position but I cannot find it.

So does anyone know where I should look to alter the CSS or is there a better fix for this?

Here is what the form looks like now:

[image: Here is what the form looks like now]

Comment: Can you post the codes so that we can see what you´ve done so far ?

Comment: <Form.Label>Event Date</Form.Label>
<Form.Control
       type="date"
       name="event_date"
       value={date.value}
       className={classnames('form-control', { 'is-valid': date.error === false }, { 'is-invalid': date.error })} />

Comment: @Olasunkanmi I figured it out, thanks though!

Answer (score 8):

[Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

I saw this thread and their solutions/suggestions worked for me. My specific solution follows:

1. I created a new css file with the following code --

   ```
   input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
   }

   input::-webkit-datetime-edit {
     position: relative;
     left: 15px;
   }

   input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
     position: relative;
     left: 15px;
   }
   ```
2. Then I imported it into my form file and it worked.

[image: See it now]

Answer (score 3):

Following answer of [@Cody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13758141/cody), it worked, however date value of input box were floating right, out of box like this:

[image: With left: 15px;]

Made a small change in `left` for `edit`, which worked perfectly:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { position: absolute; left: 0; }
input::-webkit-datetime-edit { position: relative; left: 0; }
input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper { position: relative; left: 0; }
```

Here is the look after this change:

[image: With left: 0;]

Answer (score 1):

I also used the style options found here:
[Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

And found this to be the simplest way to position the calendar to left:

```
input[type="date"] {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row-reverse;
   padding: 8px;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: We had a similar strategy, but as of chrome/edge 112, this no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I made these changes for extra left padding in dates.

```
input[type="date"] {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-reverse;
    padding: 8px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}


input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
}
```