# How to style selected days in input type="date" HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, date, input

I need to use a calendar for my React app where user can choose multiple days.

So far I only found the react-date-picker module but I don't really like its CSS customisation.

I thought it would be better to use HTML tag input type="date" if there is such an opportunity as it looks nice on all mobile devices(my app is for mobile devices only).

On desktop the behaviour of this element is different from the smartphone, it closes each time the user chooses the date but I don't need desktop and on smartphones the calendar is not closing after the click which is great, however, I want to style selected days somehow with the background so the user would see what he chose.

I figured out how to add all those dates to an array and it basically works OK on smartphones but the problem is I can not style the calendar the opens up.

Can anybody suggest how do I go about styling the days user clicked on? Because by default it shows background for the last date you chose and that's it.

This is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-days-picker-input-type-date-tag-z1zgk?file=/src/App.js:502-512)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm either blind or there is no option to style selected days. Could you please tell me exactly which of the answers explain how to style the drop down calendar?

All I see is examples of styling the input itself but not the calendar that opens up after click

Comment: That's the point; there is no option to style the selected days for input type="date". The question has been asked (what are the options?) and answered (there are none).

Comment: Oh, I did not get this. Alright then, thank you. Not sure how to mark your comment as an answer though.

Comment: It should prompt you to accept the the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

HTML does not provide such kind of `<input>`.

You can use [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) for ranges.

Or, [MultiDatesPicker](https://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/) to be able to select specific days.

Comment: Does this library allow to choose random dates, not within a range? I don't see such an option there.

Comment: By default you can select any date range. If you want to specify an authorized range, you can use `minDate` and `maxDate` properties. See the library documentation. Don't forget to validate my answer if it helped you, it is appreciated on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is still the range. I need a solution when the user could choose for example Monday, Thursday, Sunday only.

Comment: I see. You can use https://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/ for that.