# how to change color of the placeholder of date input html tag?

Tags: html, css

I already know how to change the placeholder value's color, but the same is not possible with the date input tag, please tell me how to do so,

```
<input type="date" />
```

Comment: You will find the answer to your problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be done with JavaScript.

```js
document.querySelector('input').onchange=function(){
  this.style.color="black";
}
```

```html
<input type="date" style="color:red" />
```

Comment: actually i didnt wanted to change its color on clicking, i just wanted to set it to white so that it can be visible on grey background, but {style="color:red"} this line helped me a lot, thanks. i was trying to do it in css, but i think inline css is better as well.

Comment: @ShivangShukla Glad to help :)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Change Placeholder Color</title>
</head>
<style>
::placeholder { /* Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
    color: blue;
}
  
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: red;
}
  
::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: orange;
}
</style>
<body>
    <p>Change Placeholder Color</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Text">
</body>
</html>
```

You can check here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/change-an-html5-input-placeholder-color-with-css/

Comment: Thank you for noticing

Comment: @ShivangShukla had specifically mentioned input type date which behaves differently than input type text.