# How to use CSS to style native HTML5 datepicker

Tags: html, css, web

There appears to be no current information how to style the native HTML5 (not the input aspect) datepicker (refer to image).  As you see it appears in standard blue.  I cannot access through the inspector.  May someone help.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Comment: The pop-up with calendar is browser specific. As far as I know you can only format the `.input` field.

Comment: Thanks.  
I appreciate that the input can be styled hence the image to show what I would like to style.  I guess you are saying that the browser specific pop-up cannot be over-ridden :(