# Style native date picker's pop-up menu

Tags: html, input, webkit, mobile-safari

I'm curious if I can style the pop-up menu which appears in native browser implementations of `<input type="date" />`, specifically the calendar grid's text colors and background:

[image]

From another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker) I see that the input box can be styled via the Shadow DOM and wanted to know if something similar existed for the pop-up part of the UI, specifically for the iOS Safari browser.

Comment: Dont use native html for this. You can use jquery's date picker too. Search for it and u will get how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Archit. I'm hoping not to use an external library. I'm mostly curious about the limitations/possibility of doing this natively.

Comment: HTML elements such as the date picker and file upload inputs are part of the browser and not the code. That's why we cant access them in our code to style

Comment: And Anyway i dont see any reason to style it as it is already beautiful.