# Customize HTML calendar widget in Vue

Tags: html, vue.js, tailwind-css

Is there any way to customize the widget (HTML Calendar Widget) background color? To be more specific I want to change the background white color in Image:

[image]

I am using Vue3 and tailwind. Thanks for the help.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16106788/17072824) but it's just specifying that how to change the style of input field