# How to change the blue color of Chrome's native date time picker?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, datetimepicker

For a native datetime picker in Chrome, how can I change the color of these blue buttons, blue text and blue calendar date indicator using css?

[image]

Comment: Don't use it?  You have to create a "custom" one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Comment: No it only changes the input element but not anything in the actual date picker dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

In short words, you can't. That's something that can vary among browsers and it's not specific to Chrome.

The recommendation would be to build one from scratch with JavaScript, or the best approach is to use a library to implement datetime pickers and customize them like Material UI https://mui.com/components/date-time-picker/