# Is there a way to hide the native Safari and Firefox datepicker

Tags: html, date, firefox, safari, datepicker

There doesn't seem to be any way to hide the native datepicker from Safari and Firefox.
Any ideas? Or should I just scrap the `<input type="date" />` and use a normal `<input type="text" />` for my datepicker for Safari and Firefox? I only saw ways to style the input as is shown here [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

I've tried inspecting and searching for the popup in the DOM, but it doesn't seem to be there.

Help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Still impossible to my knowledge

Comment: Try `event.preventDefault()` on the click event. That might work.