# Why are the "date" and "time" entries not displayed correctly in Google Chrome Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small scheduling system that I developed ([Look here](https://ledevwd.github.io/agendamento/)).

The "date" and "time" entries are showing normally in most desktop and mobile browsers:

[image]

But for a reason I don't know! In Google Chrome Mobile, a gray background color appears in the "date" and "time" fields. Also, the default icons are gone:

[image]

I tested in all browsers, but this only happens with Google Chrome Mobile. I want to fix this soon, I don't know what's going on and I've been at this for 1 week.

I'm using Chrome version 101.0.4951.41.

This is the project repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/ledevwd/agendamento).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the border property on the input: Chrome Mobile is setting the background of the date and time inputs to match the border.

I'm guessing you'd like all your inputs to match, so setting a background colour on inputs within your form will have the desired effect:

```
background-color: #fff;
```

I would also recommend not removing the `outline`, as that is used for accessibility reasons (screen readers).

So your whole style would look like this:

```
#form-field input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #a3a3a3;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Date and time inputs are relatively new and so cross-browser support is tricky (Safari Mobile notoriously didn't support a date picker for years). [MDN has some guidance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#handling_browser_support) on detecting browser compatibility.

Comment: And are the missing icons and default values ​​"dd-mm-yyyy" and "--:--" also browser behaviors?

Comment: I don't think the date format (dd-mm-yyyy vs yyyy-mm-dd etc) is standardised between browsers as yet, though it's been a while since I've looked at it. It *should* default to the users locale settings. For example, UK users will have the day first, month second, but US users will have month first, day second.

Comment: I'm on my phone at the moment so I can't check your link, but did you set a colour on the icons? If they're SVG you may need to set the `fill` colour.

Comment: The first icon in the first field I added, however the last two icons are the browser's default. The first icon appears normally, but the last two disappear. See the effect on your own mobile.

Comment: Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker) - using a `filter` could help. As mentioned in this thread though, it will vary between browsers still. As I've supplied links to existing threads and MDN, my answer should still be accepted. :)

Comment: I have tested all the examples, but on chrome mobile still, the default icons and texts disappear. I think the most sensible would be to use Jquery ([Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)) and set the field value to a current date.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because of browser native control styles. You can override it by **appearance/webkit-appearance:none** property. after you need to give your own style to the component.

Please do more R&D on **appearance/webkit-appearance** and it will resolve your problem.

I have set `appearance:none` and see the below result. It's remove all arrow and make simple `textbox`

[image]

Comment: I've tried doing it this way, but it didn't work. If you have code that spot the problem it can help a lot.

Comment: @Leandro Please view my updated comment as above. I have set appearance: none property and it's works fine..