# How to change the size of the input type=date popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

is it possible to change the size of the popup window of the `<input type="date" />`? This is relatively small

The size of the input element is adjustable via ::webkit-datetime, but I haven't found any records of the popup calendar.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't because it's a native element. If you use a library for date selection, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread  : [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

> The following eight pseudo-elements are made available by WebKit for
> customizing a date input’s textbox:
>
> ::-webkit-datetime-edit ::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper
> ::-webkit-datetime-edit-text ::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field
> ::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field ::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field
> ::-webkit-inner-spin-button ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator