# Is there a way to change HTML Date picker's popup background color?

Tags: html, css, date, datepicker, calendar

Here, I am using

`<input type="date" style="position: absolute">` tag to create a date picker. I want to change the default white color background to another color. Is there anyway to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Comment: @BrettDonald No dear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this code.i have used to color-scheme css**

```css
.datepickerbg {
  color-scheme: dark;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="datepickerbg" />
```

Comment: Damn! This works! Thanks for your answer :)

The only limitation when using color-scheme is we have limited number of predefined values. As below,

color-scheme: normal;
color-scheme: light;
color-scheme: dark;
color-scheme: light dark;
color-scheme: only light;