# Remove placeholder from date type input in chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, google-chrome, date

I have the following input:

```
<input class="AccordionLeft" id="operationDate" name="OperationDate" type="date" value="">
```

This shows the date format as a default placeholder. I would like to remove this placeholder and just have an empty input field.

If I do this:

```
`$('#operationDate').val('@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")');`
```

I get today`s date as the placeholder, but if I use this:

```
$('#operationDate').val('');
```

I get the placeholder like `dd-mm-yyyy`.
Can the placeholder be removed entirly? I have seen several posts about changing the date format, but have found none about removing the placeholder completley.

Comment: What you're looking for is not to change the `input` type? From `date` to `text`? Or I didn't get your question.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - I am looking to remove the `mm-dd-yyyy` placeholder. The text that is displayed in the input by default, before any value is selected.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387655/disable-new-chrome-date-types-input-formatting-and-placeholder

Comment: @MelanciaUK - Thanks for the reply. I looked at that question before. I think it has more to do with the date format that is displayed.

Comment: @Maks3w Maybe, but since my question is older, technically, that is a duplicate of this and not the other way around...

Comment: I choose this way because the target does not have references to jQuery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hide the format placeholder with the following style rule:

```
<style>
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:not([aria-valuenow]) {
    color: transparent;
}
</style>
<input type=date>
```

Comment: This has no effect at all, and also you are missing the actual selector and an opening brace.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for the missing '{'.  But it should work if you add {.  http://jsfiddle.net/int32_t/DA3Nn/

Comment: Sorry, you`re right. I had something I tried overriding the placeholder. Can you add the missing `{` for completeness and I'll undo the downvote. Thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the selector for the slash separators is `::-webkit-datetime-edit-text:not([aria-valuenow])`

Comment: This no longer works.

Answer (score 21):

You could achieve a nice effect using `onfocus` and `onfocusout`, along with some CSS.

```html
<input name="date" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')">
```

Comment: That's a nice trick!

Comment: Working perfect
Very original solution :) gz

Comment: It should be `<input name="date" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value)this.type='text'">`

Comment: Very nice man, Like!

Comment: Unfortunately, as of Dec 2016, this does not work on iOS. It renders the input field as text on load and does not re-render when the input type is dynamically altered with JS