# Remove default text/placeholder present in html5 input element of type=date

Tags: html, css, date

I am using html input element with type as date,

```
<input type="date">
```

When I use above element it creates a default date format i.e. mm/dd/yyyy text within that input element. How do I remove this default text?

I tried adding below style on my page but it is hiding the selected date value as well,

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Are you only targeting Webkit/Blink user agents? Neither Gecko nor Trident support the date input type at the moment.

Comment: @TiesonT. thanks for your response; I just noticed that Trident and Gecko are not supporting this. However I am trying to run it on Blink(Chrome) at the moment. Any suggestions ?

Comment: can someone share a working solution for 2020 please?

Comment: I have answered this here (get rid of 'mm/dd/yyyy') : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76764124/7233526

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:not([aria-valuenow]) {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: @Steffi A. Thank you.. Your suggestions works perfect!

Comment: Or another answer `<input name="date" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value)this.type='text'">`

Comment: Does not work in chrome 51.0.2704.103, Mac OS El Capitan. http://take.ms/P7SSK any ideas?

Comment: Does not work in chrome 60.0.3112.113, Win 10 pro either. Seems like this selectors got changed or removed.

Comment: @FabianSchöner Correct, Chrome no longer supports any kind of additional selector on pseudo-elements. In case your date element is not restricted (no min/max), you could use: ```input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field,
input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
 color: transparent;
}```

Comment: @HaiNguyen please post this as a separate answer

Comment: @Steffi A. What can we use if we have min/max values. Please help me Sir.

Comment: Is there a way to get the answer from @SteffiA. to work on disabled input fields where input[type="date"].

I have also found that changing the color to transparent still leaves the padding for the placeholder. You can always set display: none if you don't want that extra padding in your input field.

Comment: Actually never set it to display none. Because then you won't be able to see yourself typing in the dates which is a bad user experience.

Answer (score 24):

Possible option

HTML:

```
<input type='date' required>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=date]:required:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=date]:focus::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: by any chance can two selectors work together?
leg. if required is invalid and field is disabled apply transparent.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work anymore on latest chrome versions. Tested it on Version 50.0.2661.102 and didn't work.

Works by adding this instead:

```
.mdl-textfield:not(.is-dirty) input::-webkit-datetime-edit {
     color: transparent; 
}

input:focus::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .46) !important; 
}
```

[Working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/cm5e8frx/)

[Source](http://qnimate.com/guide-to-styling-html5-input-elements/)

Comment: this seems to make the value disappear even when set (chrome 54)

Comment: This answer does work in chrome 60.0.3112.113 on win 10 pro, but it doesnt only remove the default value but also makes a set, valid value disappear on blur.

Comment: by any chance can two selectors work together?
eg. if required is invalid and field is disabled apply transparent.

Comment: makes the value disappear also

Answer (score 6):

For *Chrome*

```
input[type='date']:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field,input[type='date']:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,input[type='date']:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,input[type='date']:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-text{  color: transparent;}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer might be more helpful to others if you explained how/why it works, and/or why this solution is better than the existing answers that have already been here for a while :)

Answer (score 5):

To sum the previous, I think the simplest, most general and reliable css suggestion could look as follows:
`input[value=""]:not(:focus) { color: transparent; }`
Works fine for me in Opera 83 and Chrome 98.
Just wondering why no one brought this here before.

Comment: Works in Edge too!  Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome 110

Answer (score 3):

This works in chrome and doesn't make the value dissapear when set (Version 74)

```
input[value=""]::-webkit-datetime-edit{ color: transparent; }
input:focus::-webkit-datetime-edit{ color: #000; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input name="date" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(!this.value)this.type='text'">
```

Thank to Hai Nguyen.

Comment: This should never be done, as it will wrongly report the type of the input to assistive technology. It will mess up with input autocompletion.

Answer (score 2):

#### This should be transparent only when value is not set.

```
input[value="0000-00-00"]::-webkit-datetime-edit {
     color: transparent; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in chrome as of Version 73.0.3683.103

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit { color: transparent; }
:focus::-webkit-datetime-edit { color: #000; }
```

I couldn't figure it out for Edge though so i changed it to this

```
input[type=date] { color: transparent !important; } 
.active input[type=date] { color: inherit !important; }
```

this may not be good for some of you but i was adding the class of active anyway as my labels hover of the input field until clicked and then i move them up out the way. Hence why i needed to not display the date placeholder while the label was over the input

Answer (score 1):

this worked fine for me:

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

  input[type=date] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
  }
```

Comment: For me none of these has made the placeholder disappear in Chrome 79.0 and Firefox 72.0

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with `datetime-local`, this worked for me, maybe someone can use it. Text input is much easier than datetime to style

```
type='text' required='' onfocus="this.type='datetime-local'" onblur="if(this.value==='')this.type='text'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide the **icon placeholder** only (for using your own icons), this is enough for inputs of *type="date"* and *type="time"* in Edge, Chrome and Firefox:

```
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
   opacity: 0;
   cursor: pointer; /* optional */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome 110 I ended up using:

```css
/* remove default browser placeholder when not focused */
input[type='date']:not(:focus):in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field,
  input[type='date']:not(:focus):in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
  input[type='date']:not(:focus):in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
  input[type='date']:not(:focus):in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
    color: transparent;
  }

/* iOS background fix */
  & > input[type='date']:empty {
    background-color: #f9f9f6;
  }

  /* iOS fix for text alignment */
  & > input::-webkit-date-and-time-value {
    text-align: left;
    color: var(--sg-black);
  }

  /* iOS date-placeholder fix */
  & > input[type='date']:not(:focus):empty:after {
    position: absolute;
    color: #aaa;
    content: attr(placeholder);
  }
}
```

In addition to that, I'm removing the placeholder when a value is set:

```
<input
  type='date'
  placeholder='Choose date'
  ref={dateInputRef}
  onChange={() => {
    if (!dateInputRef.current) return;
    if (dateInputRef.current.value) {
      dateInputRef.current.placeholder = '';
    } else {
      dateInputRef.current.placeholder = 'Choose date';
    }
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: Finally, a solution that works! I just needed it for desktop so I just needed the first block of css. Hides the placeholder when not in focus. Shows the placeholder when the control has the focus. Shows the date when a valid date is entered. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

This may be late but this worked for me.

```js
document.addEventListener('focusin',function(e){
  e.target.type = 'date';
});

document.addEventListener('focusout',function(e){
  e.target.type = '';
});
```

```html
<input class="my-date" placeholder="Select Appointment Date"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and solved it by adding a separate class to keep track of the state.  Tried various solutions here and in other places and none seemed to solve the issue.  So set the field opacity as 0 by default, and then use event listener for input event, if there is input, add the class `has-text`, and then style that text.

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar issue to this, I opted for a variance on the answer supplied by @Vladimir Kovarsky

Specifically I wanted to retain the control at a class level, given the class might be manipulated at run-time:

```
input[class~="empty-date"]:not(:focus) {
    color: transparent;
}
```

The above assumes I have an input with a class of 'empty-date' applied, e.g.

```
<div class="col"><input type="date" class="empty-date form-control"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="col"><input type="date" class="form-control empty-date"/></div>
```

The key being the usage of '~=' (contains).

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can take advantage of the default placeholder generated by Chrome by using the following code. This code also works with dates fetched from the database:

```
<div class="Input">
    <script>
        function getDate() {
            var GET_DATE = document.getElementById("ThisElement").value="<?php echo $GetDateFromMySQL = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row_FetchedResults["MySQLColumnName"]));?>";
            return  GET_DATE;
        }
    </script>

    <input class="form-control"
           style=" text-align: left; border: none;" 
           onfocus="(this.type='date')"  
           onblur="
               if(this.value===''){
                   this.type='text';
                   this.value='';
                   this.value= getDate();
               }
               else{
                   this.value;
               }"                       
           id="ThisElement"  
           type = "text" 
           value = "<?php echo $GetDateFromMySQL = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row_ActiveStudents["ChaseUpDate"]));?>"                
     />
```

Answer (score -1):

this is worked for me

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll(".date-input");

input.forEach(function(e){
  e.addEventListener("focusin",function(ev){
    e.type = 'date';
  })
});
input.forEach(function(e){
  e.addEventListener("focusout",function(ev){
    e.type = 'text';
  })
});
```