# MDL date placeholder

Tags: html, css, datetime, material-design-lite

I am using MDL - getmdl.io version 1.3.0

I am having a problem getting the date form field to do what I want. instead of only showing the label field, it is showing the placeholder from the default `<input type="date">`.

I ideally don't want to show this. But if I have to, how can I put the label next to the form field?

code

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="date" id="date">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="date">Date</label>
  </div>
```

My CSS attempt to hide the default placeholder.

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
  color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MDL has a built-in yet undocumemnted solution: `has-placeholder`. This will make the floating label fixed, always floating

Add 
`mdl-textfield--floating-label has-placeholder` classes to the outer  element.

Credit: @Jurgen
[How to create textbox with fixed label in Material Design Lite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647278/how-to-create-textbox-with-fixed-label-in-material-design-lite)

Answer (score -1):

Add this instead:

```
input::-webkit-datetime-edit{ color: transparent; }
input:focus::-webkit-datetime-edit{ color: #000; }
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686288/remove-default-text-placeholder-present-in-html5-input-element-of-type-date)