# Material-UI TextField - renders Text over default Text

Tags: reactjs, label, material-ui, textfield

I am using the Material-UI `TextField` Component and there is this problem, that it renders for TextFields of type "date" and "time" the format of its value. Just like this: 
[image]

I need that "TT.MM.JJJJ" and "--:--" removed.
At this point my code to render those field looks like this:

```
<TextField
    label={label}
    type={type}
    value={value}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true
    }}
    onChange={(event) => this.onChange(event)}
    margin='normal'
    variant='outlined'
    disabled={disable}
  />
```

Comment: Material-UI is limited with the time and date options. You can't really get rid of that (you can use CSS to hide it). There are alternative libraries for handling time and date

Comment: Adding to Idan's insight, you can make use of a somewhat related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686288/remove-default-text-placeholder-present-in-html5-input-element-of-type-date) which could help you.

Comment: Thank you @minu.273 that seems to work for chrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove default text/placeholder present in html5 input element of type=date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686288/remove-default-text-placeholder-present-in-html5-input-element-of-type-date)

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @minu.273 and @Idan I found the solution.
I have put the following Code in a .scss file:

```
input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field, input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field, input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field, input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-text { color: transparent; }
```

That works for chrome