# C# Blazor date input

Tags: c#, date, input, blazor

I'm doing a simple date input with C# blazor and I have a slight problem. Default placeholder of the input date field is string "mm/dd/yyyy" it represents null value. I tried to change that placeholder to show nothing, but for some reason it still shows "mm/dd/yyyy" if the value is not picked. If I choose any kind of date then my new set date is shown in the field. There are photos and a code snippet. The types are DateTime?.

```
<div>
     <input type="date" value="@(data.WorkerScheduleStartDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)(data.WorkerScheduleStartDate)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : string.Empty)"
     @onchange="async (args) => { data.WorkerScheduleStartDate = DateTime.Parse(args.Value.ToString());
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This seems to be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28686510/1492496