# How to remove the placeholder text of input[type="date"]?

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

I have an `input[type="date"]` with min/max range. What I am trying to achieve is to hide the placeholder text displayed in any language as of dd/mm/yyyy. What have tried so far is adding the following CSS.

```css
input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field, 
input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field, 
input[type="date"]:in-range::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field {
    color: transparent;
}
```

But that doesn't produce the intended output, as I have a range validator on the element.

Comment: What trying to achieve is to have the dd/mm/yyyy hidden at all times, even on focus in/out, while at same time have the "value" entered visible at all times

Answer (score 3):

You could swap out placeholders using a `::before` pseudo-element:

```css
input[type="date"]::before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  color: #999999;
}

input[type="date"] {
  color: #ffffff;
}

input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:valid {
  color: #666666;
}

input[type="date"]:focus::before,
input[type="date"]:valid::before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<input type="date" placeholder="Date" required>
```

Comment: Playing around with this a bit on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#try_it it seems only

`input[type="date"] {
    color: #ffffff;
}

input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:valid {
    color: #666666;
}
`

is needed

Answer (score 2):

The following works on Chrome. I am not sure about the other browsers. Safari doesn't seem to have an `input` of type `date`

```js
const $input = $('input');
$input.on('input', function(){
    $input.addClass('focused')
});
```

```css
input::-webkit-datetime-edit { 
    color: transparent;
    user-select: none;
}

.focused::-webkit-datetime-edit{ 
  color: #000; 
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='Date' />
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686288/remove-default-text-placeholder-present-in-html5-input-element-of-type-date) Stack Overflow post for more information

Comment: tried adding the above to my css, but still the placeholder dd/mm/yyyy appears? isn't the dd/mm/yyyy considered a placeholder or is there another pseudo-element to allocate that display text??

Comment: this hides the placeholder correctly, but disallows selecting and inputting date, the date input doesn't show the selected values anymore and doesn't allow inputting data by keyboard

Comment: You can now see it when you focus the `input`.

Comment: nice, but what am trying to achieve, as a requirement, is to have the value field always visible, while not have the placeholder visible; non visible value on focus out doesn't satisfy the requirement of the application

Comment: The latest edit hides the `dd/mm/yyyy`, but after focusing, it shows the value always. Hope that helps

Comment: It uses jQuery but.

Comment: JQuery is no issue, the issue is that will need the dd/mm/yyyy hidden at all times, both when focus is in/out

Comment: not when focus is in, it still prints the dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

On pure HTML & Javascript the following code can be of use

```html
<input
  type="date"
  name="dateInput"
  id="dateInput"
  value=""
  style="padding-left: 4.2rem;"
/>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput");

    dateInput.addEventListener("input", function () {
      var inputValue = dateInput.value;

      if (inputValue) {
        dateInput.style.paddingLeft = "0rem";
      } else {
        dateInput.style.paddingLeft = "4.2rem";
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

On Angular

```html
 <input
      type="date"
      name="dateInput "
      value="{{ dateInput }}"
      [(ngModel)]=" dateInput "
      [ngStyle]="{'padding-left': dateInput ? '0rem' : '4.2rem'}"
    />
```

this code just pushes the default `mm/dd/yyyy` out side of the width of the input .. the `4.2rem` is just what i used for my case and you'll need to change the value to suit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Placeholder?

```
input[type="date"]::before{
content: attr(placeholder);
position: absolute;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

input[type="date"]{color: rgba(0,0,0,1);}
```